# Swapping x and y axes in octave 6.2.0

Tags: histogram, octave

I have a problem with the x and y axes of my octave histogram. Instead of appearing with the x-axis the data index and the y-axis the data values, just the opposite is happening. See the figures. Can someone help me please?

```matlab
function plot_histogram(bel)
   N = length(bel);
   x = 1:N;
   x = x';
   hist(bel);
   %view([-90 90])
   %axis([0 N 0 1])
end
```

bel is a 20-position vector with values that add up to 1.

---

Image of what the histogram should look like
[image]

---

Image of what the histogram looks like

[image]

Comment: Could you show your code? Else we're just guessing in the dark.

Comment: (1) Is it Octave or MATLAB that you're using? What version? Use only one of the two tags. (2) What is the data you're plotting a histogram for? Please see [mre].

Comment: If `bel` has 20 values, then you expect the histogram bins to add up to 20, which they do (y axis). And if the values in `bel` add up to 1, then you expect them all to be much smaller than 1, again consistent with the histogram (x axis). Your "should look like" plot is no a histogram (y axis is not a count). Maybe you are looking for `bar(x,bel)` (or just `bar(bel)`)?

Comment: A histogram tells you how many occurrences there were within specific bins. you have twelve values in the first bin, and two values in each of the other bins.  It appears you do not want a histogram, but some distribution function. Maybe you could explain how you generated the 'should look like' plot, and we can help you figure out what you actually want to do.